# How to re-use the parameters as variables in multi commands

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I want to save the typing and define the variables in powershell, then re-use it with other commands, i got error.

```
Import-Module Az.Cdn -Force

$cdnProfile = "abc_test"
$resourceGroupName = "test_dev"

$cdnProfileParameters = "-ProfileName $cdnProfile -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName"

$cdnProfile = Get-AzCdnProfile $cdnProfileParameters
$endpoint = Get-AzCdnEndpoint $cdnProfileParameters
$azCustomDomain = Get-AzCdnCustomDomain $cdnProfileParameters -CustomDomainName "www.example.com" -EndpointName $endpoint.Name -ErrorAction stop
```

it failed at first command `Get-AzCdnProfile` with error

> Get-AzCdnProfile: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-ProfileName abc_test -ResourceGroupName test_dev'.

Comment: In PowerShell you need to declare the variables with $variable= "value" Refer this documentation on how to [declare variable in powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7.2#working-with-variables)

Comment: i already updated that part, same error

Comment: Looks like you want to use **splatting** (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3) so something like ```$params = @{ "ProfileName" = "abc_test"; "ResourceGroupName" = "test_dev" }; $cdnProfile = Get-AzCdnProfile @params``` - note it's a ```@``` not a ```$``` in ```Get-AzCdnProfile @params``` - that's what activates splatting...

Comment: Looks promise, let me test

Comment: Thanks @mclayton, this works. Can you answer it, so I can accept it as answer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by **mclayton**, you can make use of below PowerShell script to achieve your scenario.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

I created an Azure CDN profile:

[image]

I used the below PowerShell script to retrieve the CDN profile:

```bash
$cdnProfileParameters =  @{ "ProfileName" = "testcdn"; "ResourceGroupName" = "RG" };
$cdnProfile = Get-AzCdnProfile @cdnProfileParameters
```

[image]